# How to load Custom Block .phml file from an Overrided admin controller?

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, template

I have override an adminhtml controller `Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController`.
I am trying to load a .phtml file from one of my Custom module as like below

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('custommodule/blockname')->setTemplate('custommodule/file.phtml');

$html = $block->getHtml();
```

But since i am in an Admin controller, the system tries to setTemplate in under

`adminhtml/default/default/template/custommodule/file.phtml`

But the file i want to load is under

`frontend/default/default/template/custommodule/file.phtml`

The system throws error like, the template path does not exists.
I am aware that this is happening since we are in an admin controller, and
the system tries to load the admin layout file. Trying to see the possibility
of doing this.

Suggest me a solution.

**Note : This code works well when i call it from a front end controller.**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set `frontend` area for your block before setting template

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('custommodule/blockname')
    ->setData('area','frontend')
    ->setTemplate('custommodule/file.phtml');
```

The same you can also do in layout xml file

```
<block type="custommodule/blockname" template="custommodule/file.phtml">
    <action method="setData">
        <key>area</key>
        <value>frontend</value>
    </action>
</block>
```

Comment: Works like charm! +1